# provider and driver-DSN

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

Is it possible to get provider from database driver (DSN). I got list of all odbc dsn and from the driver can i derive provider information? whats the relation between driver and provider. Also how can i check whether sqlserver is the back end or mysql

Answer (score 1):

As far as my (basic) knowledge goes, ODBC uses drivers and OLE DB uses providers. You can extract the driver name from an ODBC DSN using the [OdbcConnection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx) and the provider name from an OLE DB connection using the [OleDbConnection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx).

As for telling the difference between MSSQL and MySQL, you can make the choice part of your installation/setup process or try executing a query that is specific to each platform. The best answer probably depends on which ORM or DAL you're using.

Comment: What i mean is when you create DSN using control panel you point to a database. it can be msaccess or sqlserver. So how do i check programatically it points to sql or mysql.

Comment: As I said, you can retrieve the driver name from the DSN. There are lots of examples including driver names here: http://www.connectionstrings.com